# fix a point on the android screen while camera movement

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-canvas, preview

I am developing an application where I drew a point on the camera preview using canvas. Now I want to fix the point on the screen though camera is moved up/down, left/right.

My question is, 
Is it possible to fix the point on the preview screen?

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?